# C unsigned int comparison - wrap around on custom bit number

Tags: c, types, unsigned, integer-arithmetic

I am reading a 24-bit value, presently into a `uint32_t` variable.

After bashing my head against the wall calculating the difference between two such variables, and thinking "it's unsigned! Why is this overflow a problem?!", I realised the values are overflowing short of the size of the variable containing them.

This is a counter, so one is known to be 'larger' than the other, though may have overflowed.

Thus, `0x1 - 0x2 = 0xFFFFFFFF`, but should be `0x00FFFFFF`.

How should I best deal with this?

- Define a type `uint24`;
- `if`/`else` on which is larger before doing the appropriate arithmetic;
- Something else I haven't thought of?

'best' should be interpreted as 'best practices'/'most readable'/'safest'.

Comment: 1. Can you give an example of the problem you're having? With inputs and expected result. 2. Do you want the result of the subtraction to be signed or unsigned?

Comment: @interjay Result is also unsigned - this is a counter, so one is known larger; signed result would be meaningless/MSb wasted.

Comment: Then I don't see what the issue is. If you subtract the smaller number from the larger there will be no overflow.

Comment: @interjay Well `0x1 - 0x2` will be `0xFFFFFFFF`, but should be `0xFFFFFF`.

Comment: I don't get why you are using `-` operator two compare two numbers, since you have plenty of relational/equality operators `<`, `<=`, `!=` and so on. I agree that some self-contained example would be useful.

Comment: If one number is known to be larger, what's the value in subtracting 0x1 - 0x2?

Comment: @interjay it's 'larger', but may have overflowed

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski The resulting value, difference, is used. Excuse my poor choice of word.

Comment: If the 8 most significant bits are not used, why do you care if they are `0` or `0xFF`?

Comment: @ouah Because they are used, I stupidly didn't think of interjay's `&0xFFFFFF`, so I was getting incorrect results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To subtract (or add) two numbers and have the result wrap around the range of an unsigned 24-bit number, do a binary-and of the result with `0xFFFFFF`, i.e. `(x-y) & 0xFFFFFF`. For example:

```
(0x1 - 0x2) & 0xFFFFFF == 0xFFFFFF
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, you can use compare operator `!=`, `==`, `>`, `>=`, `<` and `<=`. you don't need do such as `num1 - num2` if you want to compare...

Anyway, if it's really necesaary, just use bitwise AND

```
uint32_t n1 = 1, n2 = 5;
printf("0x%08x", (n1 - n2) & 0x00ffffff);
```

[(live example)](http://ideone.com/eRz5Rf)

Output:

```
0x00fffffc
```

As you know, `0xfffffc` means `-4` in 24-bit signed integer.

(Notice that 2's complement is *not* specified by C standard; my code may not work in non-2's complement system.)

Comment: Yes, it is specified for unsigned types. (The standard describes it roughly as: Let **M** be the precision of the type, then the result of expressions is the arithmetically correct result modulo **2^M**; which is effectively 2’s complement.)

Comment: @mafso yes, but strictly speaking, standard does not force 2's >o<

Comment: Not by that term, yes. My point was, your code is guaranteed to work, even on a non-2’s complement machine.